# “By whom” vs. “By who” with passive modal for forming questions

Tags: passive-voice, modal-verbs, wh-questions

Consider this sentence:

**Children should be taught appropriate behavior by their parents.**

If We want to question the actual doer of the action (*their parents*), are these correct?

- By whom should children be taught appropriate behavior?
- By who should children be taught appropriate behavior?

Comment: If it's the object of a preposition **and** immediately after that preposition, use _whom_. But if you want to question the subject, why use the passive? _Who should teach children appropriate behavior?_ The purpose of the passive is to de-emphasize the subject and emphasize the object; if you then want to focus on the subject in a question, you're defeating the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“By whom”
(If you must use passive voice)